# Firefox refresh current tab from command-line

Tags: firefox, shell, automation

I'd like to trigger a tab refresh on Firefox from a command line. I'm working on a web app and the refresh goes after the app compiles. I trigger the compile from a command in my IDE. It's not a fixed url, nor can it be derived from the open file in the IDE. Thus, the currently open url in the active tab.

The thing is, I'm in a double headed box with no Xinerama support, which means I can't alt+tab to Firefox, instead I must move the mouse to the other screen, click on Firefox and then Ctrl+R. That can't be right.

I tried some sort of bookmarklet stuff, like `DISPLAY=':0.1' firefox -remote 'openurl(javascript:alert(1);)'` , but FF wouldn't run that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you could do it via a custom command line handler extension.

Comment: Is there such a thing already? Or would I have to make one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an updated version of @geekQ's script that will return focus to the previous program (however, the firefox window will still be pulled to the top).

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT_WID=$(xdotool getwindowfocus)

WID=$(xdotool search --name "Mozilla Firefox")
xdotool windowactivate $WID
xdotool key F5

xdotool windowactivate $CURRENT_WID
```

Comment: For the original problem it wouldn't matter if Firefox is pulled to the top, as long as `$CURRENT_WID` remains on focus. Very nice, thanks!

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad this little script was helpful to you too!

Answer (score 33):

You can use xdotool for automation. Install on Ubuntu with

```
sudo aptitude install xdotool
```

Then you can search for windows and send keys or mouse events, see `man xdotool` for the full documentation. I use following script on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS during development:

```
WID=`xdotool search --name "Mozilla Firefox" | head -1`
xdotool windowactivate $WID
xdotool key F5
```

Note: in the older versions, e.g. Ubuntu 14.04 the flag is `--title` instead of `--name`.

See also the [xdotool project site](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/).

Comment: +1 [verified](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/f9ab9549f61892c09f40abd384f42a91f006ac40).

Comment: works, though it has a bad side effect of switching to the firefox window

Comment: When using `--title` I get: `This flag is deprecated. Assuming you mean --name (the window name).`

Comment: @ŁukaszGruner see my answer to automatically switch back to the previous window.

Answer (score 6):

With the `--window` option from the man-page it's actually a one-liner and quicker:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

xdotool key --window $(xdotool search --name "Mozilla Firefox") F5
```

---

edit:

..and even *better using inotify* to watch for file changes:

```bash
# refresher - send an F5 to a selected window on file change events
#!/bin/bash

project_root=$(pwd)
excluded=".*\.(swp|log|.*~)"
wid=$(xdotool selectwindow)
# ..waiting for user to select browser window..

while inotifywait --quiet --event modify --recursive --exclude "$excluded" $project_root
do
  xdotool key --window $wid F5
done
```

Answer (score 2):

For OS X you can do it with these few lines of applescript:

```
activate application "Firefox"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "r" using command down
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nifty tool named IMACROS from IOPUS.
You can write macros for the browser, then call the macros from a script.